# Calculate depth of pixels

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

is it possible to calculate the depth of two pixels given that you have

- The pixel coordinates p1 and p2
- A displacement vector D = P2 - P1 of the corresponding pixels in world space
- The intrinsic camera Matrix K (there is no camera translation or rotation)

Shouldn't it be possible to infer the world coordinates of the points P1 and P2? I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: yes, with the intrinsics you can describe the 3D line from the projection center through the pixel plane into the scene. With two 3D lines you can calculate the points on both lines where they have some chosen distance. But: Probably multiple 3D position combinations on both lines can have that same distance. If you have additional assumptions like "P1 and P2 have similar depth" or your actual D (if relative to camera coordinate system) the it should work (depending on you needed accuracy).

Comment: if you have more than 2 points (4 or 5?) it becomes easier: Just use opencv's solvePnp function.